# Librería BarcodeLib

Tags: c#, windows-forms, visual-studio-2015

Intentando instalar [BarcodeLib](https://github.com/barnhill/barcodelib) en mi proyecto Visual Studio 2015 framework 4.6.1 no me deja instalar, me da el siguiente error.

> No se pudo instalar el paquete BarcodeLib 2.2.1. Está intentando instalar
>   este paquete en un proyecto que tiene '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' como destino, pero el paquete no contiene referencias de ensamblado o archivos de contenido compatibles con dicho marco. Para obtener más información, póngase en contacto con el autor del paquete.

Pero sin embargo si he podido instalarlo en Visual Studio 2017 framework 4.6.1 sin ningún problema y ambos tienen en el app.config la misma configuración de framework

```
<startup>
<supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" />
</startup>
```

¿Como puedo solucionarlo?

Comment: pero el mensaje esta muy claro, vas a tener que cambiar la version del framework de .net que usa tu proyecto, ya que la libreria no lo soporta

Comment: @LeandroTuttini Pero en Visual Studio 2017 si funciona con framework 4.6.1

Comment: pero tu proyecto que version de .net framework esta utilizando ? tiene que ser 4.5.1 o superior

Comment: @LeandroTuttini Conoces de alguna librería que pueda crear una imagen de barcode que sea free

Comment: @LeandroTuttini esoty usando la 4.6.1

Comment: @LeandroTuttini el problema si es que cambio de framework mi app trabaja con una librería de SqLite 4.6.1 derrepente puede dejar de trabajar si bajo a la versión 4.5.1

Comment: Pero dices que con 4.6.1 lo referencia correctamente, entonces no entiendo. No tienes que bajar a 4.5.1, podrias ver de quitar el supportedRuntime a ver como se comporta

Comment: Mi proyecto real esta desarrollado en Visual Studio 2015 framework 4.6.1 pero las implementaciones de concepto o de pruebas lo hago en Visual Studio 2017 por que estoy probando esa versión de pasada comente lo que me dijistes y me da el mismo error. No se que se debera.

Comment: @LeandroTuttini tampoco se puede instalar en framework 4.5.1 en Visual Studio 2015

Comment: la verdad no entiendo el problema, si creas un proyecto nuevo con .net 4.6.1 agrega la referencia? si lo hace listo

Comment: Ya lo instale utilizando VS 2017, seguiré trabajando con esta versión, solucionado